How do I make datetime2 work with odbc, DBI in R
I connect to a SQL Server, where I have a table with a column col_time of datatype datetime2(7) supporting seven decimals (100 ns precision).
con <- odbc::odbc() |> DBI::dbConnect(...)

I have a time:
ts <- lubridate::now()
tbl <- tibble::tibble(col_time = ts)

I want to write that now to my database:
con |> dbWriteTable("test", tbl, append = T)

But the time is only saved to the table with three decimals. How come? If I write SQL code directly in SQL Server Management Studio, of course, it works e.g.
INSERT INTO TABLE test (col_time) 
VALUES ('2024-01-01T12:34:56.1234567')

What's going on? I have a feeling that odbc doesn't support datetime2? Do I have to change something? Would that help? I am using the driver "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server".

So even though many people say, "use datetime2 instead of datetime", it is in fact useless for my usecase, because ODBC reduces it to exactly the same precision as datetime.

I dunno r, but you can probably store the value as string with the desired datetime2 format and then it will probably work. Although, not sure why you need datetime2, unless you're measuring some higgs particles

I can get 6 decimals by running options(digits.secs = 6) before the call to now().

@OlympusMons digits.secs only shows me the value in R with more digits, but it doesn't write it with more digits to the database.

@siggemannen Thanks for the typical stack overflow answer. No we are not working in theoretical physics, but yes, there are applications where you want precision better than milliseconds.

A solution using the Native Client 11.0 driver that can be downloaded from Microsoft here. It may work with other drivers but I only had this one.
First connect to the server
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(

  odbc::odbc(),

  driver = "SQL Server Native Client 11.0",
  server = "...",
  database = "...",
  Trusted_Connection = "Yes"
)

Configure R to use 6 digits precision which I think is the most R can do
options(digits.secs = 6)

Since passing the time variable directly results in only 3 decimals we convert ts to a string which will contain all the digits
ts <- lubridate::now()
ts <- toString(ts)

Now proceed as in the question code
tbl <- tibble::tibble(col_time = ts)
con |> dbWriteTable("test", tbl, append = T)

If the datatype of the column col_time in the test table on SQL Server is datetime2(7), the variable ts will now have been stored in the test table with 6 decimals.
SQL Server 2008 was used.

Thanks for the answer. We also saw that we can mitigate this issue by converting to a string beforehand. Of course it would be nicer to have this wrapped in the library. After all, that's why we use libraries like odbc or DBI... but at least that's a feasible solution.

As long as the right time format is used where the months and dates cannot get mixed up. E.g. 01-02-2024 can mean february 1 in europe and january 2 in the USA. The yyyy-mm-dd format is safe to use, as explained here
